# Ansible-pull does not find vars in group_vars directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have an ansible structure that contains some roles.

```
/usr/local/ansible
    playbooks
        roles
            role1
            role2
                tasks
                handlers
                files
                templates
                    my_template.yml
                vars
                    main.yml
    group_vars
        role2.yml
```

Usually, when running this from the ansible server, the template: module finds group_vars/role2.yml and applies it to my_template just fine.

When I use ansible-pull the template module cannot find the group vars and the first template line that references a variable causes an error - can't find the variable.  Only by putting my variables in vars/main.yml can we find them.

```
ansible-pull -C dockervm -d /usr/local/ansible -U git@github.com:MRI-Software/HappySoftware-config-usr_local_ansible.git -i localhost, -e 'small=yes vagrant=True ServerNamePrefix=docker' --accept-host-key /usr/local/ansible/playbooks/docker.yml
```

Since the ansible-pull operation leaves behind the entire /usr/local/ansible directory tree (as pulled from the git server) I tried running ansible-playbook manually and got the same failure as ansible-pull.

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost -e  'small=yes vagrant=True ServerNamePrefix=docker'  ./docker.yml
```

The main difference between this provisioning and the normal web server provisioning is that this is running against localhost.

So I made sure that /usr/local/ansible/group_vars and /usr/local/ansible/playbooks/group_vars both contained a localhost collection of variables, but the playbook still fails on the first variable reference in the template:

```
TASK [docker : template] *******************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'SSH_WEB_USER' is undefined"}
```

Yes, I checked that the variable definition was there.

So I transplanted the entire collection of variables to the roles/docker/vars directory inside main.yml and that works, but it's now an exception compared to the rest of the provisioning roles.

Any idea how to get the ansible-pull to reference the group_vars directory (in playbooks)?

Answer (score 1):

Your directories *group_vars* and *playbooks* are in the same directory */usr/local/ansible*. The command *ansible-pull* runs the playbook from the directory *playbooks* `/usr/local/ansible/playbooks/docker.yml`.

Take a look at [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). You'll see that *group_vars* can be placed either in the playbook or inventory directory (precedence 4.-7.).

- The simplest solution would be to move *group_vars* into the directory *playbooks*

```
/usr/local/ansible/playbooks/group_vars/main.yml
```

But, you'll see an error if you haven't cloned the repository *playbooks* yet

> fatal: destination path '/usr/local/ansible/playbooks' already exists and is not an empty directory.

As a result, this option works if you move *group_vars* into the already cloned repository and the option *--purge* isn't used.

- The next option is moving *group_vars* into the inventory. For example,

```bash
shell> pwd
/tmp/test

shell> tree .
.
└── inventory
    ├── group_vars
    │   └── all
    │       └── main.yml
    └── hosts

3 directories, 2 files

shell> cat inventory/hosts 
localhost

shell> cat inventory/group_vars/all/main.yml 
test_var_1: test variable 1
```

Configure inventory

```bash
shell> export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=/tmp/test/inventory
```

and run the *ansible-pull* command

```yaml
shell> ansible-pull -d /tmp/test/test_001 -U https://repos.example.org/test_001.git --full /tmp/test/test_001/pb_001.yml
Starting Ansible Pull at 2023-07-22 19:18:03
/home/admin/.local/bin/ansible-pull -d /tmp/test/test_001 -U https://repos.example.org/test_001.git --full /tmp/test/test_001/pb_001.yml
localhost | CHANGED => {
    "after": "1f637428cafb37156e4027dc459e90609a2c2192",
    "before": null,
    "changed": true
}

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Playbook pb_001.yml is runnning ...

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var_1: test variable 1

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

, where the below playbook was used

```yaml
shell> cat test_001/pb_001.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Playbook pb_001.yml is runnning ...
    - debug:
        var: test_var_1
```

Comment: Actually, I have the group_vars in playbooks and had copied it to ../playbooks as part of debugging this.  It doesn't find it in either place. I'm going to try putting it in a subdir called inventory as you suggested, and specify that on the ansible-pull line.  I'll report back.

Comment: See [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html). As part of debugging, you might want to take a look at *inventory_dir* and *playbook_dir*.